# I need help clearing a menu when I click a button to move to another screen in pygame, python

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a game. I want to code the game in a way that it has a main menu and after clicking the start button, it will open up the game. Whenever I click the start button, the menu still stays and the game loads up behind it. Please help! i don't know what to do! Find my code below:

```
def main_menu():

  while True:
        draw_text('START', font, white, (screen_width // 2 - 250), (screen_height // 2 - 0))
        draw_text('EXIT', font, white, (screen_width // 2 + 50), (screen_height // 2 - 0))
        draw_text('main menu', font, (255, 255, 255), 20, 20)


        start_btn = pygame.Rect((screen_width // 2 - 250), (screen_height // 2 + 70), 200, 50)
        exit_btn = pygame.Rect((screen_width // 2 + 50), (screen_height // 2 + 70), 200, 50)

        mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if start_btn.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            if click:
                world.draw()
        if exit_btn.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            if click:
                exit()



        click = False
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    click = True



        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), start_btn)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), exit_btn)


        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

class World():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.tile_list = []

        #load images
        dirt_img = pygame.image.load('pics/dirt.png')
        grass_img = pygame.image.load('pics/grass.png')

        row_count = 0
        for row in data:
            col_count = 0
            for tile in row:
                if tile == 1:
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(dirt_img, (tile_size, tile_size))
                    img_rect = img.get_rect()
                    img_rect.x = col_count * tile_size
                    img_rect.y = row_count * tile_size
                    tile = (img, img_rect)
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)
                if tile == 2:
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(grass_img, (tile_size, tile_size))
                    img_rect = img.get_rect()
                    img_rect.x = col_count * tile_size
                    img_rect.y = row_count * tile_size
                    tile = (img, img_rect)
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)
                col_count += 1
            row_count += 1

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(bg_img, (0, 0))
        for tile in self.tile_list:
            screen.blit(tile[0], tile[1])

world_data = [
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 7, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 7, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
]

world = World(world_data)


while run:
    main_menu()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False



    pygame.display.update()
```

if you need the full program, find that below:

```
    import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen_width = 600
screen_height = 600


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Computer Science IA')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 60

#define game variables
tile_size = 30
click = False
run = True


#define font
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Bauhaus 93', 70)
font2 = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri 9', 20)

#define colors
white = (255, 255, 255)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

#load images
bg_img = pygame.image.load('pics/sky.png')

def draw_text(text, font, text_col, x, y):
    img = font.render(text, True, text_col)
    screen.blit( img, (x,y))



def main_menu():

  while True:
        draw_text('START', font, white, (screen_width // 2 - 250), (screen_height // 2 - 0))
        draw_text('EXIT', font, white, (screen_width // 2 + 50), (screen_height // 2 - 0))
        draw_text('main menu', font, (255, 255, 255), 20, 20)


        start_btn = pygame.Rect((screen_width // 2 - 250), (screen_height // 2 + 70), 200, 50)
        exit_btn = pygame.Rect((screen_width // 2 + 50), (screen_height // 2 + 70), 200, 50)

        mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if start_btn.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            if click:
                world.draw()
        if exit_btn.collidepoint((mx, my)):
            if click:
                exit()



        click = False
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    click = True



        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), start_btn)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), exit_btn)


        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

class World():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.tile_list = []

        #load images
        dirt_img = pygame.image.load('pics/dirt.png')
        grass_img = pygame.image.load('pics/grass.png')

        row_count = 0
        for row in data:
            col_count = 0
            for tile in row:
                if tile == 1:
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(dirt_img, (tile_size, tile_size))
                    img_rect = img.get_rect()
                    img_rect.x = col_count * tile_size
                    img_rect.y = row_count * tile_size
                    tile = (img, img_rect)
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)
                if tile == 2:
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(grass_img, (tile_size, tile_size))
                    img_rect = img.get_rect()
                    img_rect.x = col_count * tile_size
                    img_rect.y = row_count * tile_size
                    tile = (img, img_rect)
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)
                col_count += 1
            row_count += 1

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(bg_img, (0, 0))
        for tile in self.tile_list:
            screen.blit(tile[0], tile[1])

world_data = [
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 7, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 7, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
]

world = World(world_data)


while run:
    main_menu()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False



    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

This is how it looks:
[Failed Main Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Er5o.png)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Just create a variable that keeps track of what to display.

```
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen_width = 600
screen_height = 600


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Computer Science IA")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 60

# define game variables
tile_size = 30
click = False
run = True


# define font
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Bauhaus 93", 70)
font2 = pygame.font.SysFont("Calibri 9", 20)

# define colors
white = (255, 255, 255)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

# load images
bg_img = pygame.image.load("pics/sky.png")


def draw_text(text, font, text_col, x, y):
    img = font.render(text, True, text_col)
    screen.blit(img, (x, y))


def draw(curr_display, start_btn, exit_btn, world):
    if curr_display == "main_menu":
        draw_text(
            "START", font, white, (screen_width // 2 - 250), (screen_height // 2 - 0)
        )
        draw_text(
            "EXIT", font, white, (screen_width // 2 + 50), (screen_height // 2 - 0)
        )
        draw_text("main menu", font, (255, 255, 255), 20, 20)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), start_btn)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), exit_btn)

    elif curr_display == "world":
        world.draw()


def main_menu(world):
    curr_display = "main_menu"
    start_btn = pygame.Rect(
        (screen_width // 2 - 250), (screen_height // 2 + 70), 200, 50
    )
    exit_btn = pygame.Rect((screen_width // 2 + 50), (screen_height // 2 + 70), 200, 50)

    while True:

        mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if curr_display == "main_menu":

            if start_btn.collidepoint((mx, my)):
                if click:
                    curr_display = "world"
            if exit_btn.collidepoint((mx, my)):
                if click:
                    exit()
        draw(curr_display, start_btn, exit_btn, world)

        click = False
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    click = True

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)


class World:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.tile_list = []

        # load images
        dirt_img = pygame.image.load("pics/dirt.png")
        grass_img = pygame.image.load("pics/grass.png")

        row_count = 0
        for row in data:
            col_count = 0
            for tile in row:
                if tile == 1:
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(dirt_img, (tile_size, tile_size))
                    img_rect = img.get_rect()
                    img_rect.x = col_count * tile_size
                    img_rect.y = row_count * tile_size
                    tile = (img, img_rect)
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)
                if tile == 2:
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(grass_img, (tile_size, tile_size))
                    img_rect = img.get_rect()
                    img_rect.x = col_count * tile_size
                    img_rect.y = row_count * tile_size
                    tile = (img, img_rect)
                    self.tile_list.append(tile)
                col_count += 1
            row_count += 1

    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(bg_img, (0, 0))
        for tile in self.tile_list:
            screen.blit(tile[0], tile[1])


world_data = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 7, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 7, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
]

world = World(world_data)


main_menu(world)
```

Also, I have improvised your code a little bit :)!

Comment: Thank you soo much! Everything is working wonderfully now! So you made a variable called current display and it changes for every menu that is displayed! That is Genius!

Comment: Glad to help!  ☺️

Comment: Hi! I wanted to know if this code will still work if I add more menus. Cause I am trying to add a new page with the draw function you made and there are a few problems.

Comment: Just add another elif statement in the draw function, and it should work for multiple menus! Also i recommend creating, a check_event function to check for , well… all the events.